# bbPress - select a topic reply as "answer"

Tags: bbpress, forum

Folks!

I have a good knowledge of Wordpress, and currently I started to use BuddyPress / bbPress to build a project. One of the goals of the project is to set a **"question and answer"** section at each BuddyPress Group. Since bbPress and BuddyPress works well together, I thought to use bbPress forums to build something like that.

So, to achieve this, the two things that I need is:

1. Upvote / Downvote a topic reply (witch I could get using a plugin such as [bbPress Post Ratings](http://wordpress.org/plugins/bbpress-post-ratings/);
2. Select a reply as an "answer", putting it at the top of the replies and highlighting it.

For the second item, I found a bbPress plugin named **"Best Answer"**, but I found only the svn repository of it (http://plugins-svn.bbpress.org/best-answer/trunk/) and not a plugin page, so I supose that this plugin is pretty old.

If anyone knows a plugin that adds this "mark as answer" feature, or knows a way to do it (or at least a hint to start developing something about it), I'll be very glad!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about making something similar, and also found those plugins to be outdated. I did create a 'Mark as sold' feature for some classifieds I recently added to my site, and I think it will use similar methods.

I haven't started development on it yet, but here's the idea I've been kicking around:

- Add post meta on creation of any post, 'votes' = 0 & 'answered' = false
- Add a link for each thing, thumbs up, thumbs down, select this as the answer, show only for logged in users, post author, whatever.
- Ajax call for update_post_meta on the appropriate key
- *(I haven't figured out listing the posts in order of up or down votes)*

Let me know if you want to bounce some ideas around, and I hope this helps get you started!